# usb audio interface 'disappears' on windows 7 wakeup

Tags: windows-7, audio, sleep, usb-audio, m-audio

Most nights I fall asleep listening to music - sometime during the night, my computer goes to sleep. When I wake it up the next morning, my external audio device (M-Audio Fast Track Pro) get 'lost' somehow. It doesn't appear on the list of available audio devices, it's not in the device manager, it's not in the audio device properties, etc. Turning the device off and then on again doesn't have any effect - stopping and starting `audiosrv` doesn't do anything. (and drivers are up to date, naturally, and this issue has persisted through several rounds of updates)

Restarting the computer makes everything work perfectly again - until the next time it wakes up and forgets about the fast track again.

Comment: You could try to unplug and re-plug your external audio device to see any changes. Also as it's usb plugged-in then you can also try this (Goto control panel -> power options -> select your enabled power plan -> Change plan settings -> advanced options -> goto USB settings -> usb selective suspend setting and disable it.

Comment: changing power settings sounds promising. the problem is intermittent, so it's tough to tell what effect that has - I'll keep an eye on it now.

Comment: hmmm, nope, happened again, with disabled selective suspend.